# Efficient algorithm for generating graph edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a set of vertices with 3D spatial coordinates of size N and a maximum connection distance d, is there an efficient algorithm to find all the undirected edges connecting the vertices with distance less than d; loops are not considered. A naive approach would simply loop on all possible pairs, requiring N(N-1)/2 distance calculations. Is there an existing algorithm for finding all possible edges with scaling complexity less than O(N^2)?

Comment: Are you trying to create a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with graphs. It is about 3D Euclidean distances.

Comment: This reminds me of [3D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection). If so start with bounding boxes.

Comment: @GuyCoder good point, this is the same problem as collision detection. Recursive boxing methods like quadtree can do this in N Log(N).

Comment: Note that you can't do better than O(n^2) in the worst case because the output size is O(n^2), e.g. when all the points are within distance d of each other. You can only do better if you have some expectation about the distribution of the points.

Comment: @kaya3 if we assume that each point will only be within collision distance of a finite number of other points such as atoms in a molecule, is there any algorithm that can exploit this to give O(N) performance on average?

Comment: @mTesseracted Since you already have an upvoted answer to the question as written, if you have a related question with extra requirements please ask it separately.

Comment: Of interest: Wikipedia Collision detection [Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Optimization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a set of vertices with 3D spatial coordinates of size N and a
> maximum connection distance d, is there an efficient algorithm to find
> all the undirected edges connecting the vertices with distance less
> than d

Yes.  Insert the vertex locations into a octree, then for each vertex search for vertices closer than d.

For the equivalent problem in 2D you can use a quadtree.

You can find C++ quadtree code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree

Example Usage:

```
        // construct vector of random points
        std::vector<cPoint> vp = random(count);

        // construct quadtree of points
        cCell quadtree(cPoint(0, 0), 100);
        for (auto &p : vp)
            quadtree.insert(p);

        // quadtree search
        // returns vector of all points within 2 by 2 box around point 10,10
        auto fp = quadtree.find(cCell(cPoint(10, 10), 2));
```

Note that if the exact Euclidean distance is important, then post-processing is required to remove any points in the red regions.

[image]

For more details, check out the German tv mini-series 'Billion Dollar Code' available on Netflix.

Comment: Do you know of any collision detection algorithms that have O(N) average case performance where the average case is each object only collides with a finite number of other objects?

Comment: @mTesseracted If those are the constraints of your problem then you should have included them in the question. Please don't wait until someone has done the work to answer the question as you wrote it and then change what you're asking for.

Comment: Since the OP asks for a 3D solution, an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) is more appropriate.

Comment: @LiorKogan  Good point.